# Bootstrap 5 sizing utility / flexbox bug

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am currently creating a Shopify theme using Bootstrap 5 that I have been building and testing using Google Chrome on my Macbook.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<body class="template-{{request.page_type | handle}} d-flex flex-column vh-100">

  {% section 'header' %}

  <div role="main" class="container-fluid flex-grow-1" id="mainContainer">
    <div class="row h-50" id="customize">
      Hello
    </div> 
  </div>

</body>
```

The relevant CSS for this question is all vanilla Bootstrap5 so I won't bother posting that. In the code you can see that I have a body that has bootstrap classes `d-flex flex-column vh-100` so that it is a flex item with column orientation that takes up 100% of the viewport. Inside this we have a header which takes up dynamic space, and then a div containing the rest of my content. This div has the `flex-grow-1` class so that it will take up the rest of the viewport after the header.

Inside this container I have a single row, with the bootstrap sizing utility class `h-50`, meaning that 50% of the remaining viewport that the container uses should be the row. In Google Chrome for desktop, which I had been using to wireframe, you see the expected output:
[website in chrome for desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5mIA.jpg)

However, I viewed the website on a number of other devices (Chrome for mobile, Safari for mobile and desktop), and the result I am seeing is that the row is not being resized. I am using the developer tools and seeing that the bootstrap is still being loaded (the `h-50` class is still being applied). Furthermore, the container is still flex-growing which I checked by setting its background-color to red, However the child row for some reason is NOT resizing 50% of the container:
[website in safari for desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J32ER.jpg)

I am using the latest versions of all browsers that I use, so I am a little baffled as to what is going on. Feel free to look at the website, it is located at me-marcel-dev.myshopify.com with access code breert. Thank you for any help you. may be able to provide.

EDIT: I am narrowing it down to some behavior with flex-grow though Im still not quite sure why its behaving the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Setting flex-basis to 100% seemed to do the trick. I got that answer from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/